# jQuery custom content scroller: auto scroll on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) plugin and would like the scroll initiated automatically when the page loads.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems simple enough - the API provides a `scrollTo` function so it's just a matter of wiring it up with a jQuery `ready` handler.

Comment: scrollTo just move the content to a specific ponint. I would like the content move automatically on page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2), is not just this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html, body').scrollTop(25);
});
```

?

Comment: I try this:
    $(".wrapperContent").animate({scrollLeft: 900}, 2000);
But not work.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understand, but you could use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // or $(window).load(function() {
 $(selector).mCustomScrollbar();
 // And if you meant to change the scroll position:
 $(selector).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",Integer);
})
```

Comment: Is something like this. But the scrolling must be continuous. Like this: http://biapupo.com.br/home.php

Comment: then maybe you should use the smoothDivScroll plugin from jQuery: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ which obviously does what you want. You can look into the scroll.js from the webpage you just showed me as an example on how to use it.  Plus there's a full documentation on the smoothdivscroll page that should help too!

Comment: Bene, the only problem is smoothdivscroll don't have a scroll bar. And I need it.

Comment: But then you wont have the same effect.  There's a few way i would do that so here's my hints: either you take smoothdivscroll and add a scrollbar to it, either you take mCustomScrollbar() and add a smoothscrollto it (with settimeout for example) or you can customize both. If you customize both, that gives you all the liberty and control but requires more skills. If you start from one plugin or the other, you might waste some times trying to patch whats not working with what you want.  The only other solution would be to find a smoothscroll that already has a scrollbar but I can't do that now

Comment: Thansk Bene. I wil try something.

Comment: You can ask if you have any problem doing that!